# Retornar datos enviados de los input de formulario enviado

Tags: laravel, formularios

Va relacionado con el scaffolding he realizado el  artisan make:auth y crea todo lo necesario para el registro modelo, controlador y vistas. Me surge una duda en lo siguiente.

Cuando realizo el formulario de registro y lo envio al controlador , mi forma de hacer la creacion del usuario es :

Este seria el controlador

```
public function create( $data )
{
    User::create($data); ......
}
```

Realiza todo correctamente.si hay errores me devuelve al formulario otra vez.

Lo que quiero saber es **SI ME REGRESA** al form que los campos input los deje rellenos con la info que el usuario envió y que no tenga que rellenar todos los campos del form nuevamente ya que vuelve el form vacio para volver a empezar.

No detallo mas porque creo que es algo  mas general que algo netamente particular en el código, aun así si necesitan mas detalles me los pueden preguntar.

Comment: Por cierto mi version de laravel es 5.8

Comment: nos muestras lo que has investigado o hecho?

Comment: ¿No lo probaste acaso antes de venir a preguntar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes retornar lo siguente

```
return redirect()->back()->withInput();
```

Y en tu formulario debes agregar lo siguente

```
<input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" value="{{ old('nombre') }}" >
```

El old colocara en el value el valor que estaba previamente. El string que esta dentro del old() es el name del input

Comment: Gracias Alonso, si el tema es que estaba pegado en ello y la verdad no me habia aclarado mucho , sobre todo en el tema de los select que por cierto no os especifique en la parte de arriba, lo he solucionado. Gracias por tu aporte